# Split String every 2 characters with Zip in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I need to make a function that receives a String and a number and split this String every 2 characters but if the length of the String is not even I have to add the number. Here's what I got so far.

```
def splitString(string,number):
  if (len(string)%2 != 0):
    return list(map(''.join, zip(*[iter(string)]*2))) # I don't know how to add the number at the end
  else:
    return list(map(''.join, zip(*[iter(string)]*2)))
```

As this is for homework I was told I can't create a list and then use .append() so I have to return the list ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close:

```
def splitString(string,number):
  if (len(string)%2 != 0):
    return list(map(''.join, zip(*[iter(string + str(number))]*2)))
  else:
    return list(map(''.join, zip(*[iter(string)]*2)))
```

Example:

```
>>> splitString("hellow", 4)
['he', 'll', 'ow']

>>> splitString("hello", 4)
['he', 'll', 'o4']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really easily achieved using [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to search for substrings of 2 characters in the string with the number appended to it:

```
import re

def splitString(string,number):
    return re.findall(r'..', string + str(number))

print(splitString('hello', 3))
print(splitString('farewell', 3))
```

Output:

```
['he', 'll', 'o3']
['fa', 're', 'we', 'll']
```